# C++ generic iterator

Tags: c++, generics, iterator

I'm not sure if the answers I was able to find are the easiest way to do what I need. The simple template that I would know how to modify into a full solution to my problem would be code that accomplishes the following:

1. Takes as input two iterators pointing to the beginning and end of an iterable container (vector, list...) containing things of value type T.
2. Returns a `std::vector<T>` containing an element-by-element copy of the input container in whatever order accomplished by iterating the input container from beginning to end.

Something non-functioning would be like follows:

```
 template<typename Iterator, typename T>
 std::vector<T> dumb_copy(Iterator first, Iterator last) { ... }
```

Problem is that I would need the compiler to somehow check that I'm given iterators pointing to something of type T.

I'm currently learning C++ and writing as practice the most generic implementations of certain algorithms that I can think of, so I want to get the best practices right from the start. If there's an easy way of doing this using C++11 constructs, that's fine with me.

Comment: Why do you need this? Can't you just construct the vector from two iterators? BTW standard library iterators define `value_type`, which gives you `T`.

Comment: I thought I needed this, since I hadn't gotten that far into Stroustrup yet...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use traits to remove the `T` type completely, allowing it to be determined automatically:

```
template <typename Iterator>
std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>
    dumb_copy(Iterator first, Iterator last)
{
    std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type> copy;

    // Populate the copy vector

    return copy;
}
```

In particular, note that `std::iterator_traits` has a specialization when the iterator type is a pointer, so this will allow your function to "just work" even when it is passed pointers instead of "true" iterator objects.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do this because the standard library containers already work this way. So you can create a `std::vector` from two iterators directly:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "hello"; // iterable container

    // construct a vector using two iterators
    std::vector<std::string::value_type> v(s.begin(), s.end());

    // check the results
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << v[i];
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. As I said, the point of the template is just to get the types right. What I'm interested in is implement an algorithm which will be doing a sequential walk through the input container, some non-trivial processing, and store the solution in to the vector.

Comment: @JT1 Then it sounds like you might benefit from `std::for_each()`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a `std::vector<T>` with a type matching the result of `*it` for one of the iterators:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
template <typename Iterator>
auto dump_copy(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
    -> std::vector<typename std::decay<decltype(*begin)>::type> {
    return std::vector<typename std::decay<decltype(*begin)>::type(begin, end);
}
```

With C++14 you can replace `typename std::decay<X>::type` by `std::decay_t<X>`.